# changing span text into icon with css keyframes

Tags: jquery, css, animation, plugins, css-animations

i made some text animations with the jquery typing plugin TypeIt.js (http://macarthur.me/typeit/).
Now i have following problem:
I want to animate a typed <3 to an heart-icon with css keyframes and need your help. It should not be on hover, it should change after a specific delay (maybe 1sek after TypeIt.js typed my <3 text.

Here's my code which is not working:

```css
.hearticon {
    animation-name: switch;
    animation-delay: 1s;
    animation-duration: 0.7s;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@-webkit-keyframes switch {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    background: url(img/heart.png);
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
  }

}

@keyframes switch {
    from {
      opacity: 0;
    }

    100% {
      opacity: 1;
      background: url(img/heart.png);
      width: 15px;
      height: 15px;
    }

  }
```

```html
<span class="hearticon"><3</span>
```

I have to say that i never worked with css keyframes before.
Thanks for helping

Answer (score 0):

I'd use `position: absolute;` for this case in your keyframe animation.  I'd also suggest using the shorthand string for your animation.  It's a bit more efficient in terms of writing less AND when a page loads, it doesn't have to go through 5 lines of code - instead it reads 1 line and yet does the same thing.  Simple tip to help w/ performance anyway.

As for your question, below works of what you asked for.

HTML:

```
<span class="hearticon"><3</span>
```

CSS:

```
.hearticon {
  animation: switch .7s ease-in forwards 1s; //Shorthand string versus having 5 lines of code here...('switch' = animation-name), ('.7s' = animation-duration), ('ease-in' = animation-timing-function), ('forwards' = animation-fill-mode), and ('1s' = animation-delay)
}

@-webkit-keyframes switch {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    background-image: url("http://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/148/148836.png"); //Put your own image here
    position: absolute;
    width: 128px; //Adjust to your size
    height: 128px; //Adjust to your size
  }
}

@keyframes switch {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    background-image: url("http://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/148/148836.png"); //Put your own image here
    position: absolute;
    width: 128px; //Adjust to your size
    height: 128px; //Adjust to your size
  }
}
```

Other tips:
When working with keyframes, you may want to think about using vendor pre-fixes for firefox, IE and opera as well.  I see you have chrome and safari which uses the **-webkit-** pre-fix, but if you want your site to be compatible across multiple browsers, I'd suggest adding **-moz-**, **-o-**, and **-ms-** as well.

Ex:

```
.hearticon {
    -ms-animation: switch .7s ease-in forwards 1s; //Used for IE
    -webkit-animation: switch .7s ease-in forwards 1s; //Used for chrome & safari
    -moz-animation: switch .7s ease-in forwards 1s; //Used for Mozilla Firefox
    -o-animation: switch .7s ease-in forwards 1s; //Used for Opera
  animation: switch .7s ease-in forwards 1s; //Will become standard
}
```

as well as:

```
@-ms-keyframes switch {
  0% {
        // Your code here
    }
  100% {
        // Your code here
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes switch {
  0% {
        // Your code here
    }
  100% {
        // Your code here
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes switch {
  0% {
        // Your code here
    }
  100% {
        // Your code here
    }
}
@-o-keyframes switch {
  0% {
        // Your code here
    }
  100% {
        // Your code here
    }
}
@keyframes switch {
  0% {
        // Your code here
    }
  100% {
        // Your code here
    }
}
```

And finally, a working [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/su7j99j0/1/)